# Is there a way to use the parameter as a prefix in a C macro in GCC

Tags: c, macros

I am trying to do some template stuff in C: 
I need to create a 2d-vector struct with functions to work with them and I need to have them for the types int, unsigned int, float, double and maybe even other types that all support basic math functionality.

I could write all the code for every type. If I write an bug in one of them, I may forget to fix the bug in all others. I did it before in C++ and I just used templates, but now that I want it in C (C11)... there are none.

So I look at macro's, and I see that it is possible to use the ## tag to literally use the macro's passed parameter.

Here's some code I tried:

```
#define DECLARE_VEC2(N, T) \
  typedef struct { T x, y;} N; \
  inline N *##N_new() { return malloc(sizeof(N));}

DECLARE_VEC2(vec2i, int);
DECLARE_VEC2(vec2f, float);
DECLARE_VEC2(vec2d, double);
```

It doesn't work. The ##N is not replaced with vec2i/vec2f/vec2d but just remains ##N or even simply N. The compiler won't accept it and when I run gcc with the -E flag on the file, I see that the preprocessor indeed doesn't replace it.

If, however, I add a space between ##N and the _new, the preprocessor does replace it, but the space is also there which obviously gives problems when compiling it.

If, however, I change the function name to new_##N, it not only preprocesses fine, but is also working flawlessly.

BUT I DON'T WANT THE LATTER!
I create all my structs with functionality this way: typename_function() and don't want to change it because of this stupid problem.

So, the question is: is there a way to solve this?

Note: I also tried stuff like adding an extra parameter to the macro containing the underscore, or even declaring a macro within the macro adding the underscore, but they all come to the same problem: there is need for some kind of separator that makes the preprocessor understand that the name ends before the underscore or whatever is behind it.

Edit: strangely enough, when using something like ##N##_new(), the preprocessor replaces the name fine, but then won't accept it with errors like:

```
error: pasting "*" and "vec2i" does not give a valid preprocessing token
   inline N * ##N##_new() { return malloc(sizeof(N));}
```

although the resulting code seems to be correct (gcc -E):

```
typedef struct { int x, y;} vec2i; inline vec2i *vec2i_new() { return malloc(sizeof(vec2i));};
```

Comment: `inline N * N##_new(void)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`##` is not a prefix operator, it's an infix one — a binary concatenation operator similar to `+`. So you'd use it like this:

```
#define DECLARE_VEC2(N, T) \
  typedef struct { T x, y;} N; \
  inline N * N##_new() { return malloc(sizeof(N));}
```

Note that whitespace around `##` is ignored, so if you consider it more readable, you can also do this for identical effects:

```
#define DECLARE_VEC2(N, T) \
  typedef struct { T x, y;} N; \
  inline N * N ## _new() { return malloc(sizeof(N));}
```

This should also explain why you were getting the error "does not give a valid preprocessing token": you were effectively trying to concatenate `*` and `int` into a *single* token.

Comment: Wow, ok, that wasn't well explained in the book I learnt it from. It now seems to preprocess/compile fine (although I am getting a linker error about an undefined reference to function vec2f_new, do you know why)?

Comment: @scippie About the book: maybe they somehow mixed it up with the `#` (convert to string) preprocessor operator, which is indeed prefix? About the linker error: unfortunately no idea, my primary language is C++ and I am not familiar with the exact semantics of `inline` functions in C (since this is one of the areas where the two languages differ significantly).

Comment: Thanks... I solved it by adding the static keyword. Now the functions are repeatedly added to every file that includes the header file as unique functions for that file and inline for optimization.

Comment: The semantics of `inline` by itself in C99 are difficult to explain and almost never what you want.  `static inline` is more like how `inline` behaves in C++, and makes more sense.